# Hibernate: An entity copy [Event#XXX] was already assigned to a different entity [Event#XXX]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two kinds of entities: Event and Schedule. I am trying to modify them avoiding transactions as much as possible not to lock the database for unnecessary time.

So instead of:

```
@Transactional
public void modify() {
    Event event = em.find(...);
    //... something that might take a long time
    event.addSchedule(schedule);
    em.flush();
}
```

I am trying rather to:

```
public void modify() {
    Event event = em.find(...);
    //... something that might take a long time
    event.addSchedule(schedule);
    repository.merge(event);
}

...
@Transactional
public void merge(Event event) {
    em.merge(event);
    em.flush();
}
```

The problem is that like this I am getting exceptions: `An entity copy [Event#XXX] was already assigned to a different entity [Event#XXX]`. I do not copy the entity, nor do anything unexpected with it.

Also, it is said that it is necessary to have properly implemented equals() and hashCode() methods. I have them, but as I've studied the stacktrace, it seems that the entities are compared not by equals, nor hashCode, they are compared with `==` as shown here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.3.Final/org/hibernate/event/internal/EventCache.java#62

They use IdentityHashMap, which specifically use `==`.

So where can I look for problem? I've tried hibernate from 4.1.7 to current 4.3.4 and I am using `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` to load entities without explicitly having session.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this issue by changing the Cascade type from All to Persist on all the relationships of the issued Class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem in the implementation of the equals/hashcode of `Event`:

> An entity copy [Event#1000] was already assigned to a different entity [Event#1001]

An entity copy is a Java object in-memory which corresponds to an entity in the database. There could be several copies in-memory pointing to the same DB record.

The message says that there are two `Event` objects with different  database identifiers (the `@Id` column),so from a point of view of database identity (`obj1.getId().equals(obj2.getId())`)  are not the same.

But from a point of Java equivalence (`obj1.equals(obj2)`) they are considered the same. But two objects cannot be different in the database and the same in-memory, which causes the error.

The solution is to fix the equals/hashcode implementation, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550511/illegalstateexception-with-hibernate-4-and-manytoone-cascading) for further details on the problem and this [page](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) for details on implementing equals/hascode for Hibernate entities.